# Consistency of $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, forcing

It is known that if $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega$ then $0^\#$ exists.

I am familiar with the Feferman-Levy model in which $\omega_1$ is singular, which has the same consistency strength as $ZF$. I have three questions in this matter:

1. Can the Feferman-Levy construction be carried out to turn $\omega_5$ to be singular, while $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_4$ are still regular; can we force the cofinality of $\omega_5$ to be any of the cardinals smaller than itself by the same method? (Of course $5$ was completely arbitrary, and my question is to generalize this to any $n$)
2. Since having $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega$ implies $0^\#$ the consistency strength needs to be relatively strong (i.e. more than weakly-compact, or rather at least $0^\#$...), but how strong is it?
3. I know that it is possible to have *all* uncountable ordinals singular, and that the proof assumes quite the strong hypothesis (a class of <s>supercompacts</s> strongly compact cardinals, if I recall correct), how much can we deduce from $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_k)=\omega$ for all $k<n$, for some $n$?

(The third question might be less suited to this website, but it fit in here anyway)

Comment: I'm posting a small bounty before finally posting this on MO.

Comment: Do your first and second question have a definite answer by now?

Comment: @Lorenzo: The first one is easily done with the same method as the FL model. Yes. The second one still doesn't have a definite answer. We know that consecutive singulars imply there is an inner model with a Woodin, and we know that from infinitely many Woodin cardinals we can produce a model of AD (in which there are infinitely many consecutive singular cardinals). So the actual consistency strength is somewhere between one and infinitely many Woodin cardinals. But we don't really have the technical tools to provide the exact strength at this point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The person you want to ask about consistency strength is Ralf Schindler. Years ago ("[Successive weakly compact or singular cardinals](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2586755)", Symbolic Logic 64 (1999), no. 1, 139–146) Ralf showed that the existence of two consecutive singular cardinals implies the existence of an inner model with a Woodin cardinal. The paper assumes an additional background assumption that nowadays we now how to remove using recent work of Jensen and Steel, giving the result I have stated.

I expect more can be obtained using the technique known as the "core model induction", but the problem becomes much harder trying to go past one Woodin cardinal (in particular, the core model induction requires something like a bit of choice in the background universe, and we cannot make this assumption here. There are other serious technical obstacles. They appear here and also in the result from the next paragraph).

Ralf's student Daniel Busche looked at this problem in his thesis. In their joint paper "[The strength of choiceless patterns of singular and weakly compact cardinals](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.001)", Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 159 (2009), no. 1-2, 198–248, they show that the assumption that *all* uncountable cardinals are singular implies determinacy (i.e., $\omega$ Woodin cardinals) in consistency strength.

In fact, I expect this should imply (significantly) more, but you should keep in mind that Arthur Apter proved that from determinacy one can obtain models where all uncountable cardinals *below $\Theta$* are singular ($\Theta$  is very large under the assumption of determinacy). His paper is "[AD and patterns of singular cardinals below $\Theta$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275606)", J. Symbolic Logic 61 (1996), no. 1, 225–235. There he also shows that one can get a model where the only regular cardinals below $\Theta$ are $\omega$ and $\omega_1$.

Let me now make a silly remark on whether a "Feferman-Levy kind of construction" is possible. I assume this means in particular that you want the forcing to be possible over $L$, where $0^\sharp$ does not exist. Suppose, for example, that we want to have $\omega_3$ singular while $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are regular. Then there is a subset $A$ of $\omega_3$ of small order type cofinal in $\omega_3$. Assuming $0^\sharp$ does not exist, it follows from covering that, in $L$, there is a superset $B$ of $A$ (so $B$ can also be taken to be cofinal in $\omega_3$), with $|B|\le|A|+\aleph_1$. This means that true $\omega_3$ is a singular cardinal in $L$. This already would make the construction rather different than for the Feferman-Levy model. I'll see if I can add something of substance later.

Comment: Thanks, I am writing from my iPhone so I'll be brief. The Feferman-Levy was intended to be extended as turning $\omega_n$ to be the first singular with some cofinality. Not in relation to the other questions per se. Many thanks, anyway.

Comment: I have rectified the first question. Do you think I should ask this on MO?

Comment: Andres: Thank you very much for the added paragraph. However, how much covering do we have without choice? That is, I know that $\lnot 0^\#$ is equivalent to the covering theorem under ZFC, but is it also the case without choice?

Comment: Hi Asaf, yes, covering in the form being applied here is valid without choice.