# Is every function from $\aleph_0 \to \aleph_2$ bounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $f$ is a function $f:\aleph_0 \to \aleph_2$, does it mean that the range of f is bounded in $\aleph_2$? Does this hold for all regular cardinals?

Comment: Well, it doesn't quite hold for _all_ regular cardinals in place of $\aleph_2$, just uncountable ones :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Recall that given a cardinal $\kappa$ the *cofinality* of $\kappa$, $\mathrm{cf} ( \kappa )$, is the least cardinal $\mu$ for which there is an unbounded (cofinal) function $\mu \to \kappa$.  Regularity means that $\mathrm{cf} ( \kappa ) = \kappa$, and all successor cardinals are regular.

---

***Added to indoctrinate others into Asaf's anti-Choice programme***

Note, also, that there is a fair bit of Choice involved in the above.  Without the Axiom of Choice it is possible that that $\aleph_2$ is *singular*; in particular it could have cofinality $\omega$, meaning that *there is* an unbounded function $\aleph_0 \to \aleph_2$.  The answers to [this old math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54761/8348) and well as [this slightly more recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/147090/13653) contain a wealth of information on the broader topic.

Comment: Seeing there is an abundance of answers, I feel there's no need for another answer. I expect you to be the one to add a line about the axiom of choice.

Comment: I have a programme now? Cool!

Comment: (Let me add that, even without choice, if $f:\omega\to\omega_2$ is cofinal, then for some $n$, the gap between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ must be uncountable.)

Answer (score 3):

If $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, and $\alpha$ is any ordinal less than $\kappa$, then every function $f:\alpha\to\kappa$ is bounded. In particular, any function $f:\omega\to\omega_2$ is bounded.

More generally, all functions $f:\alpha\to\kappa$ will be bounded if $\alpha<\operatorname{cf}\kappa$, the [*cofinality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality#Cofinality_of_ordinals_and_other_well-ordered_sets) of $\kappa$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the definitions of a cardinal $\kappa$ being regular is that, whenever $\alpha < \kappa$, every function $f : \alpha \to \kappa$ is bounded.

In any case, you can prove this directly, using the fact that a countable union of sets of cardinality $\aleph_1$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$: consider $$\bigcup_{n < \omega} \{ \alpha < \omega_2 : \alpha \le f(n) \}$$