# Use of the axiom of choice in a first course in ordinals

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

(It's likely that this entire question is answered with a "yes, you're right" comment. I'm just proceeding with extreme caution after discovering an error in my notes.)

I was reading my years-old university notes (Part II, Logic and Set Theory, lectured by Imre Leader at Cambridge), and I discovered a note which is by now cryptic to me.

> We did not use the axiom of choice in proving Hartogs's lemma. The only time we used AC in the Ordinals chapter was in the remark that $\omega_1$ is uncountable.

This presumably was sloppy note-taking and is false, because unless I'm horribly wrong, $\omega_1$ is *defined* (without Choice) to be the first uncountable ordinal: it's the Hartogs ordinal of $\omega$.

Someone else's notes phrased it thus:

> … apart from the remark that $\omega_1$ is not a countable supremum — which used the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

I agree that "a countable union of countable sets is countable" is a countable-choice statement, but a well-ordered union of well-ordered sets (such as ordinals) is certainly well-orderable without any choice principle, right?

My best guess is that this note is referring to the following remark, which was lectured very near to the definition of $\omega_1$:

> Every countable sequence of countable ordinals is bounded by its sup, *which is a countable ordinal*. Hence every countable sequence of ordinals "does not get close to" $\omega_1$.

Is the choicy part the italicised "which is a countable ordinal", and in fact if Choice fails, $\omega_1$ could be a countable sup (i.e. $\aleph_1$ could be singular)? This would match up with the answer of [Existence of a regular uncountable $\aleph_{\alpha}$ without $\mathsf{AC}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738494/existence-of-a-regular-uncountable-aleph-alpha-without-mathsfac) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it should have said that choice is necessary for proving that $\omega_1$ is regular. And indeed it is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that $\omega_1$ is singular.

However, you're wrong about a well ordered union of well ordered sets. For example, the real numbers could also be a countable union of countable sets (this is true in the first model in which $\omega_1$ is singular, due to Feferman and Levy). Or, the classic example of a set of socks which is a countable union of pairs which is Dedekind finite (so there is no infinite set of these pairs that admits a choice function).

Of course, if we understand "well ordered set" as a set with a specified well order, then it is indeed the case that a well ordered union of well ordered sets is well ordered. The key problem in the above examples is exactly that we cannot choose a well ordering in a uniform manner.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by the socks example here. The pairs aren't individually well-ordered, and as I understand it, that's the whole point: we need a choice principle to define a "least" sock from every pair simultaneously. So in my understanding, you have a countable (maybe even well-ordered) union of countable sets (pairs), but not of *well-ordered* sets. But I'll go and think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, then maybe you need to clarify what you mean exactly by well-ordered. If you mean that there is a well-order attached to each set, then yes, you're right. I'll clarify this in the answer.

Comment: As Bertrand Russell said, AC is needed for socks but not for shoes.

Comment: @PatrickStevens . The problem with the socks is not whether a pair can be well-ordered. As you said, if $\{P_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a set of pairs of socks, the Q is whether there exists a function $S=\{(n, S(n)):n\in \omega\}$ such that $S(n)\in P_n$ for all $n.$ Equivalently, whether there exists $\{W_n:n\in\omega\}$ where each $W_n$ is a well-order of $P_n.$

Comment: Aha, the penny finally dropped when I read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/the-cardinality-of-a-countable-union-of-countable-sets-without-the-axiom-of-cho?rq=1 . Thanks all!

Comment: @Patrick: Drop a penny, lose a penny.